# How to access a variable from another class in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt4, qpainter

I am trying to implement in Qt a main window which has 2 widgets: one area where I draw some points and one list box where I write all the points with their respective coordinates. And I would like to implement the function "delete point" of a button on the main window, i.e. when I press the button then the point selected from the list box should disappear from my area where I am drawing. So I was thinking of doing this with signals/slots, but when I try to gain access to my list of points from my drawing area it just doesn't find any containing data. This is my code until now:

paintwidget.cpp (my main window):

```
PaintWidget::PaintWidget(QWidget parent) :
        QWidget(parent),
        ui(new Ui::PaintWidget)
{
    area = new RenderArea(this);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->displayWidget, SIGNAL(listUpdated(QList)), ui->pointsListWidget,
            SLOT(onListUpdated(QList*)));
    connect(ui->deletePoints, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteItem()));
}
void PaintWidget::deleteItem()
{
    area->deletePoint(ui->pointsListWidget->currentItem());
}
```

renderarea.cpp (my drawing area):

```
void RenderArea::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    point = e->pos();
    updateList(point);
    this->update();
}
void RenderArea::updateList(const QPoint& p)
{
    list.append(p);
    if (list.count()>1)
        lineAdded(p);
    emit listUpdated(&list);
}
void RenderArea::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * /* event */)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::black,2));
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        painter.drawPoint(list[i]);
    if (list.size()>1)
        for(int j = 0; j < list.size()-1; ++j)
            painter.drawLine(list[j], list[j+1]);
}
void RenderArea::deletePoint(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    bool ok1;
    bool ok2;
    int index = item->text().indexOf(",");
    int x = item->text().left(index).toInt(&ok1, 10);
    int y = item->text().mid(index + 1).toInt(&ok2, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        //find the point with x and y as coordinates and delete it
}
```

listbox.cpp:

```
void ListBox::onListUpdated(QList *list)
{
    clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < list->size(); ++i)
        addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QString::number(list->at(i).x()) + ", " +
                                    QString::number(list->at(i).y())));
}
```

The list from the render area is a QList of QPoints. The problem is that in the FOR-loop the size of the list is 0 so I cannot see any of the points that it should contain. I think that I am failing to initialize it somewhere but I am not sure where.

The points are drawn with QPainter so when I delete the point from the list is there any possibility to delete them from my drawing area also?

Comment: where does that `list` come from? where are you adding points to your point list?

Comment: the list is from my renderarea part. i am adding the points through the signals/slots in the point list. each time i am adding a new point in the render area a signal is emitted and connected in the paintwidget to a slot from my listbox class.

Comment: how are you populating the list box? (I'm assuming that is working) If the list is empty in your render area, then you're not storing things correctly, and since you're not showing that code, we can't really know what's going on.

Comment: this is the slot that is responding to my signal:
void ListBox::onListUpdated(QList<QPoint> *list)
{
    clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < list->size(); ++i)
        addItem(new QListWidgetItem(QString::number(list->at(i).x()) + ", " +
                                    QString::number(list->at(i).y())));
}
That is how i populate the list box

Comment: please don't post code in comments, its unreadable. Edit your question next time (and use the `{}` button to format code). This still does not show where you populate the `list` in your RenderArea.

Comment: i edited my original post with my complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting you've got two `RenderArea` widgets hanging around for some reason.

You're connecting `ui->displayWidget`'s signal, but acting on the `area` widget for the delete.

Shouldn't you be calling `ui->displayWidget->deletePoint` or connecting `area`'s signal?

As for the repaint, you should call the widget's [`update()`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#update) method to have it repaint itself.